# React Native run-android error, cannot find symbol

Tags: java, android, react-native

I'm trying to make Notifications for android using NotificationCompat, i'm stuck on a problem where i get "error: cannot find symbol".
This is my NotificationService.java file.
I'm thinking that maybe the error comes from importing, but I'm not sure, stuck on this problem for long time :(

```
package com.notifikacijas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder;

public class NotificationService extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  public NotificationService(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    Log.i("NotificationService", "NotificationService Constructor");
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
    String CHANNEL_ID = "Kanaals";
    NotificationCompat.Builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.reactContext, CHANNEL_ID)
    .setContentTitle("Virsraksts")
    .setContentText("Teksts");
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "NotificationService";
  }
}
```

And there goes MainApplication.java

```
package com.notifikacijas;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.github.amarcruz.rnlog.RNLogPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
          packages.add(new NotificationService());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    initializeFlipper(this); // Remove this line if you don't want Flipper enabled
  }

  /**
   * Loads Flipper in React Native templates.
   *
   * @param context
   */
  private static void initializeFlipper(Context context) {
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
        Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.facebook.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper");
        aClass.getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class).invoke(null, context);
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my console error output.

```
/home/arturo/Notifikacijas/android/app/src/main/java/com/notifications/NotificationService.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
  private ReactApplicationContext reactContext;
          ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class NotificationService
/home/arturo/Notifikacijas/android/app/src/main/java/com/notifications/NotificationService.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
  public NotificationService(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
                             ^
  symbol:   class ReactApplicationContext
  location: class NotificationService
/home/arturo/Notifikacijas/android/app/src/main/java/com/notifications/NotificationService.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    NotificationCompat.Builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.reactContext, CHANNEL_ID)
                      ^
  symbol:   variable Builder
  location: class NotificationCompat
/home/arturo/Notifikacijas/android/app/src/main/java/com/notifikacijas/MainApplication.java:28: error: constructor NotificationService in class NotificationService cannot be applied to given types;
          packages.add(new NotificationService());
                       ^
  required: ReactApplicationContext
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Looking forward for some help, thanks :)
react-native: 0.61.5

EDIT ::
Fixed that, now after adding displayNotification(), it builds without errors, but keeps saying NotificationApp stopped working when i try to launch it.

```
  public void displayNotification() {
  Intent intent = this.reactContext.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("lv.dtg");

  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

  Uri uri = intent.getData();

  Log.i("NotificationService", "URI "+uri.toString());
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.reactContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

  String CHANNEL_ID = "notificationsChannel";
  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.reactContext, CHANNEL_ID);
  // builder.setSmallIcon(17301575);
  builder.setContentTitle("Objektā atrodas darbinieki");
  builder.setContentText("Vai vēlaties izreģistrēt darbiniekus no objekta?");
  builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
  builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
  // builder.setAutoCancel(false);

  NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this.reactContext);
  notificationManager.notify(123, builder.build());
  }
```

Comment: 1) & 2) You need to add an `import` statement for `ReactApplicationContext`.  3) missing a variable name, 4) due to `NotificationService` not compiling I think.

Comment: @StephenC Alright, I` added` import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext; Missing a variable name? Hmm? The console output is the same.

Comment: `NotificationCompat.Builder = ...` should be `NotificationCompat.Builder some_variable = ...`.  You cannot assign to a class.  It doesn't make any sense in Java.

Comment: so, also the .setContentTitle("") should be as some_variable.setContentTitle("")? It fixed the symbol problem, but still getting the constructor error..

Comment: Alright, i'll get an eye to that, thanks :), just want to know, if the way i am calling it is right, if we don't talk about argument.